# How to create individual html links with unique URL for every song by using Express.js and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

So first of all, I'm still new to Node & Express and this is my first project, that I'm still working on. My app is going to be about a website for free music sharing. The issue I'm trying to solve right now is how to make individual html pages for every track, that is uploaded, with unique URL.
Only the info of the tracks is stored in the database and the file is stored in my local folder.

The info in the database: [database](https://imgur.com/9Gxsb1h)

The modules i am using:

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
user = require('./routes/user'),
upload = require('./routes/upload');
path = require('path');

var session = require('express-session');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var passportConfig = require('./routes/passport')(passport);
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
app.get('/', routes.index); //call for main index page

// Middleware 

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/upload', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 
'./public/tracks')))

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(flash());

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
    next();
});
```

Route for the home page index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
var message = '';
var selectAllFiles = "SELECT artist,title, genre, file, users_id, users.user_name " +
" FROM music_files JOIN users " +
" WHERE users_id = users.id; ";
db.query(selectAllFiles,function(err, results){
    //console.log(results);

    res.render('home', {data: results}); 
});
```

};

This is the home page home.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<%- include header %>
        <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>


            <div id="wrapper" >
                <% for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)  { %>
                <a href='http://localhost:8000/tracks/<%=data[i].music_id 
%>'> <h4> <%= data[i].artist + " - " + data[i].title %> </h4> </a>
                <div class="tags"><span> <%= data[i].genre %></span></div>
                <audio preload="auto" controls>
                            <source src="tracks/<%=data[i].file%>">
                </audio>
                <% } %> 

        </div>

    </div>

<%- include footer %>
```

This is what i tried to make (track_id.ejs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <%- include header %>

<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>

<div id="wrapper" >

    <h4> <%= data.artist + " - " + data.title %> </h4>
    <div class="tags"><span> <%= data.genre %></span></div>
    <audio preload="auto" controls>
                <source src="tracks/<%=data.file%>">
    </audio>

</div>

<%- include footer %>
```

and the route for this page:

```
app.get('/tracks/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;
var lastInsertedTrack = "SELECT * FROM music_files WHERE music_id = ?";
db.query(lastInsertedTrack, [id], function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    console.log(id);
    res.render('track_id.ejs', {data: results});
});

});
```

When I click on the link it shows: Cannot GET /tracks/
and the url that shows: http://localhost:8000/tracks/
Can you give me any tips or some suggestions how to solve this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself. I have forgot to select "music_id" for my query in my index.js file.. That was the issue and it now runs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather try URL templating with Handlebars.js?

Comment: Add some more explanation to your answer, and possibly an example.

Comment: How is handlebars different than ejs except for the syntax?

Comment: I do not fully understand the wiring of ejs. Specially the part '/tracks/:id' confuses me while in the res.render('track_id.ejs'... is different.

Comment: I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAUncPg_FVw) which has the same thing i want to do, but this guy uses Pug (or Jade) and MongoDB, i tried a few things, but can't really solve it on my own. I also used this tutorial for some of the stuff i used. [link](https://www.js-tutorials.com/nodejs-tutorial/nodejs-example-upload-store-image-mysql-express-js/).